# Why href value is copying to input type = text while Drag and Drop?

Tags: jquery, html, browser, href

```
<a href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="clearTextbox('#search_by_userid')" title="Clear User Id"> User Id :</a> 
<span><input id="search_by_userid" type="text" value="" onkeypress="keyDownEvent(event,'#show_history_call_logs','#search_by_userid');"/></span>
```

[see it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/7qPNZ/2/)

when i click on link and Drag to any of textbox or textarea it copy the value of href to that input why its doing so ?

i know i can avoid this by doing `$("#id").attr('readonly', true).css('cursor', 'text');` or just `readonly` but in this case i don't want it "readonly"

**Is there any property of link that avoid it from copying ?** Or I am thinking wrong :(

Comment: I guess it's the common browser behavior to do that... Why would you break it ?

Comment: You are not handling the dragstart, dragend, etc events, in fact you are not doing a thing when it comes to drag and drop on that code, so the behavior you are observing is the default behavior for the browser you are using. Apparently when you drag a <a> element into an input it copies the href value, this makes sense.

Comment: @Flo-Schield-Bobby i put this Question because my QA Team report this as a Bug :( i need to fix this that's why i want to break this.

Comment: @cernunnos : Can you please suggest me How to Satisfy my QA Team that this is Browser default behavior and nothing to do with my code?

Comment: Show them your code, point to the fact that there is nowhere in your code where any of the drag events are being caught and handled. Alternatively show them a "naked" html (http://jsfiddle.net/AGWzY/), ask them to drag the link onto the input. If they are being extra stubborn ask them to replicate the bug in IE9 (as it seems it has a different default behavior).

Comment: Yeah, it appears to be on every website, just try on Stack overflow for instance, to drag a link into the search input at the top or in any answer textarea...

I'm not sure of all the browsers, but this is the default behavior of Google Chrome, and you may explain your QA team that it is not really a good idea to break it, in a User Experience point of view.

I wonder if all of this is not just a trap for you, in fact ? :)

Comment: @Flo-Schield-Bobby Lolz Thanx! There is no such thing you are thinking.

Comment: Okay, I hope you can explain them this fact, anyway !
Otherwise... Have fun :)